# Send JSON object with Java class as a client

Tags: java, json

I have made a Java class (client) to connect with the server, my requirement is to send the JSON object to server and get the response back .

I have already a JSON object however I have no idea how to send the JSON object to the server in Java.

Comment: what is the advantage to send it as an Object rather than just as a JSON string?  What is the server? (HTTP? / Socket?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it may help

```
   public boolean reset() {
        DataInputStream is;
        DataOutputStream os;
        boolean result = true;
        String noReset = "Could not reset.";
        String reset = "The server has been reset.";

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("x.x.x.x"), 3994);
            String string = "{\"id\":1,\"method\":\"object.deleteAll\",\"params\":[\"subscriber\"]}";
            is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
            pw.println(string);
            pw.flush();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(in.readLine());
            if(!json.has("result")) {
                System.out.println(noReset);
                result = false;
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = false;
            System.out.println(noReset);
            e.printStackTrace();            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            result = false;
            System.out.println(noReset);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(reset);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help , will this work for the standalone application ? as my application is not a web app .

Comment: aaah thanks a lot its worked :) m able to send the request to server . However i m gettign an error : net.sf.json.JSONException: Error while setting property=requestStatus type class java.lang.String , could you please suggest me what could be the reason of this error ?

Comment: @user3377374 i didnt get your point paste the error in other question and acpet this answer beacuse i dont know where the error is occuring its difficult to read code in comment

Comment: ok i will post new question for the error . Yes this is a right answer becoz now i am able to send the JSON object to server .

Comment: ok sure , m sorry m new :( i didnt knew that , well where is the button to click for the right answer i will do that . please elt me know .

Comment: I have posted my question , can you please have a look

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166774/error-when-sending-the-json-object-to-java-server-standalone-application

Comment: This code appears to come from here: http://danielkvist.net/code/send-a-json-object-to-server-over-tcp-connection-in-java-using-socket

Answer (score 0):

Use Restlet:

```
// Create the client resource  
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("http://restlet.org");  

// Write the response entity on the console  
resource.post(yourJsonObject).write(System.out);
```

See http://restlet.org/learn/tutorial/2.1/#part02 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) `JSON` processor to convert your `Java` Object to `JSON` String and send it to server.

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String jsonString = ow.writeValueAsString(yourObject);
```

Then you can use `HTTPClient` to post the String to server:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://x.x.x.x:3994");
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setEntity(jsonString);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
...
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Or, if you are connected using `Sockets`:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("x.x.x.x"), 3994);
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
pw.println(jsonString);
pw.flush();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(in.readLine());
....

is.close();
os.close();
```