# Error when sending the json object to Java server standalone application

Tags: java, json

I am sending the `JSON` object to server in a `Java` standalone application .

`JSON` object is :

```
{"dateFrom":"0001-01-01 12:00:00"
,"dateTo":"2014-03-29 04:34:49"
,"currency":"AUD"
,"requestStatus":null
,"dateTimeCreated":null
,"requestName":"ProjectedFundingRequest"
,"id":"af2e7ceb-c181-4a6b-a212-2867ea5cfded"
,"loginName":"mendiras"
,"securityToken":null
,"jsonString":null}

error : net.sf.json.JSONException: Error while setting property=requestStatus type class java.lang.String
```

Please let me know what could be the reason for the above error.

Comment: Do you really expect us to guess your code?

Comment: not really , just wanted to know what could be the reason of this error error : net.sf.json.JSONException: Error while setting property=requestStatus type class java.lang.String , as m new with this :((

Comment: The answer is "a mistake in the code"

Comment: Actually i havenot changed the existign code . M just sending the JSON object to the server and expecting a response .

Comment: The only thing we can say it the obvious one: your application does not like nulls

Comment: You did not even specify if you get the error on the client or on the server side.

Comment: on the server side the error is .

Comment: inspect JSONObject.java

Comment: post your java class code in which ur sending json\

Comment: yes enigneer..error in code only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing some null data in your JSON, Make sure server is accept this type of input otherwise at the time of server call it gives a error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set "requestStatus":null to "requestStatus":"",
```